# How to create a topic programmatically in JMS?

Tags: java, jms

Currently i use the glassfish admin utility to create my topic and its connection factory. And then I can get the topic by Context.lookup() method given the already created topic in glassfish. 
But now I want to create a topic programmatically according to user input, which means I don't need to first create a topic using the glassfish admin.
Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [method to programatically create jms](http://objectmix.com/weblogic/535454-what-proper-method-programatically-create-jms-topics-queues.html), there is essentially two ways:

1. Use the MBean API to create the queue/topic.
2. Use weblogic.jms.extensions.JMSHelper